# I have a weird issue with display on calculator in JS

Tags: javascript, html

Calculations are working properly and everything seems great but when I click delete, "DE"(DEL without one letter) displays on the screen next to the numbers and I can't figure out why, it may be due to textContent from html that says DEL but I'm not sure

I tried to delete MaxLength and it worked, then I went back and tried to replace -1 with -4 in CurrentNum.slice and it deleting 1 digit until the number of digits is 7 or more so I guess the problem is in MaxLength

```js
//Function elements

let ScreenNum = document.querySelector('.screen_num');
let Num = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
let Operator = document.querySelectorAll('.operator');
let Calculation = document.querySelector('.calculate');
let Clear = document.querySelectorAll('.clear');
let Buttonn = document.querySelectorAll('.buttons button');
let Decimal = document.querySelector('.decimal');
let deleteButton = document.querySelector('.delete');

//Add number on screen
let CurrentNum = '';
let MaxLenght = 7;

Buttonn.forEach(function(button) {

  button.addEventListener('click', function() {

    /*-----Max lenght-----*/

    if (CurrentNum.length >= MaxLenght) {
      return;
    }

    /*-----No 0 at start-----*/

    if (CurrentNum === '' && button.textContent === '0') {
      return;
    }

    /*-----No multiple decimal points-----*/

    if (button.classList.contains('decimal') && CurrentNum.includes('.')) {
      return;
    }

    /*-----Click decimal at start ==> 0 with decimal-----*/

    if (CurrentNum === '' && button.classList.contains('decimal')) {

      CurrentNum = '0.';
      ScreenNum.textContent = CurrentNum;

    } else {

      CurrentNum += button.textContent;
      ScreenNum.textContent = CurrentNum;

    }

  });

});

//Math

let firstNum = '';
let operator = '';
let secondNum = '';
let result = 0;

Operator.forEach(function(operatorButton) {

  operatorButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

    firstNum = CurrentNum;
    operator = operatorButton.textContent;
    secondNumb = '';
    CurrentNum = '';

  });

});

Calculation.addEventListener('click', function() {

  secondNum = CurrentNum;
  let num1 = parseFloat(firstNum);
  let num2 = parseFloat(secondNum);

  if (operator === '+') {
    result = num1 + num2;
  } else if (operator === '-') {
    result = num1 - num2;
  } else if (operator === '*') {
    result = num1 * num2;
  } else if (operator === '/') {
    result = num1 / num2;
  }

  CurrentNum = result.toString();
  ScreenNum.textContent = CurrentNum;

});

//Clear

Clear.forEach(function(clearButton) {

  clearButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

    firstNum = '';
    operator = '';
    secondNum = '';
    result = 0;
    CurrentNum = '';
    ScreenNum.textContent = '0000';

  });

});

//Delete

deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

  if (CurrentNum !== '') {

    CurrentNum = CurrentNum.slice(0, CurrentNum.length - 1);
    ScreenNum.textContent = CurrentNum;

  }

});
```

```html
<h1>Calculator</h1>
<div id="calculator">
  <div class="screen">
    <p class="screen_num">0000</p>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="number">7</button>
    <button class="number">8</button>
    <button class="number">9</button>
    <button class="operator">/</button>
    <button class="number">4</button>
    <button class="number">5</button>
    <button class="number">6</button>
    <button class="operator">*</button>
    <button class="number">1</button>
    <button class="number">2</button>
    <button class="number">3</button>
    <button class="operator">-</button>
    <button class="number">0</button>
    <button class="decimal">.</button>
    <button class="calculate">=</button>
    <button class="operator">+</button>
    <button class="clear">C</button>
    <button class="delete">DEL</button>
  </div>
  <! - - DELETE BUTTON-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the DEL button is adding text to ScreenNum cause event handler is assigned for all buttons in:

```
Buttonn.forEach(function(button){ 
...
```

I suggest two adjustments:

- first add .decimal and .operator classes to the *Num* collection:

```
let Num = document.querySelectorAll('.number, .decimal, .operator');
```

- then attach event handler to *Num* instead of *Button*:

```
Num.forEach(function (button) {
...
```

I tried here and these two changes made DEL button and the calculator in general work as intended.

have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

During checking your buttons you forget to check the delete button so I have modified you code little bit on the last else statement :

your previous code :

```
/*-----Click decimal at start ==> 0 with decimal-----*/

    if (CurrentNum === '' && button.classList.contains('decimal')) {

      CurrentNum = '0.';

      ScreenNum.textContent = CurrentNum;

    } else {

    CurrentNum += button.textContent;

    ScreenNum.textContent = CurrentNum;

    }
```

New modified code that checks if its delete button :

```
/*-----Click decimal at start ==> 0 with decimal-----*/

    if (CurrentNum === '' && button.classList.contains('decimal')) {

      CurrentNum = '0.';

      ScreenNum.textContent = CurrentNum;

    } else {
    
      if(!button.classList.contains('delete')) {
          CurrentNum += button.textContent;

        ScreenNum.textContent = CurrentNum;
      }


    }
```

Now the Delete button works fine .

```js
//Function elements

let ScreenNum = document.querySelector('.screen_num');

let Num = document.querySelectorAll('.number');

let Operator = document.querySelectorAll('.operator');

let Calculation = document.querySelector('.calculate');

let Clear = document.querySelectorAll('.clear'); 

let Buttonn = document.querySelectorAll('.buttons button');

let Decimal = document.querySelector('.decimal');

let deleteButton = document.querySelector('.delete'); 

//Add number on screen

let CurrentNum = '';

let MaxLenght = 7;

Buttonn.forEach(function(button){

  button.addEventListener('click', function(){

/*-----Max lenght-----*/

    if (CurrentNum.length >= MaxLenght) {

      return;

    }

/*-----No 0 at start-----*/

    if (CurrentNum === '' && button.textContent === '0') {

      return;

    }

/*-----No multiple decimal points-----*/

    if (button.classList.contains('decimal') && CurrentNum.includes('.')) {

      return;

    }

/*-----Click decimal at start ==> 0 with decimal-----*/

    if (CurrentNum === '' && button.classList.contains('decimal')) {

      CurrentNum = '0.';

      ScreenNum.textContent = CurrentNum;

    } else {
    
      if(!button.classList.contains('delete')) {
          CurrentNum += button.textContent;

        ScreenNum.textContent = CurrentNum;
      }


    }

  });

});

//Math

let firstNum = '';

let operator = '';

let secondNum = '';

let result = 0; 

Operator.forEach(function(operatorButton){

  operatorButton.addEventListener('click', function(){

    firstNum = CurrentNum;

    operator = operatorButton.textContent;

    secondNumb = '';

    CurrentNum = '';

  });

  });

Calculation.addEventListener('click', function(){

  secondNum = CurrentNum;

  let num1 = parseFloat(firstNum);

  let num2 = parseFloat(secondNum);

  if (operator === '+') {

    result = num1 + num2;

  } else if (operator === '-') {

    result = num1 - num2;

  } else if (operator === '*') {

    result = num1 * num2;

  } else if (operator === '/') {

    result = num1 / num2;

  }

  CurrentNum = result.toString();

  ScreenNum.textContent = CurrentNum;

});

//Clear

Clear.forEach(function(clearButton) {

  clearButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

    firstNum = '';

    operator = '';

    secondNum = '';

    result = 0;

    CurrentNum = '';

    ScreenNum.textContent = '0000';

  });

});

//Delete

deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

    if (CurrentNum !== ''){

    CurrentNum = CurrentNum.slice(0, CurrentNum.length -1);

    ScreenNum.textContent = CurrentNum;

    }

});
```

```html
 <h1>Calculator</h1>

    <div id="calculator">

    <div class="screen">

      <p class="screen_num">0000</p>

    </div>

    <div class="buttons">

      <button class="number">7</button>

      <button class="number">8</button>

      <button class="number">9</button>

      <button class="operator">/</button>

      <button class="number">4</button>

      <button class="number">5</button>

      <button class="number">6</button>

      <button class="operator">*</button>

      <button class="number">1</button>

      <button class="number">2</button>

      <button class="number">3</button>

      <button class="operator">-</button>

      <button class="number">0</button>

      <button class="decimal">.</button>

      <button class="calculate">=</button>

      <button class="operator">+</button>

      <button class="clear">C</button>

      <button class="delete">DEL</button>

    </div><! - - DELETE BUTTON-->

  </div>
```

Comment: When the answer is printed, the `DEL` button still works. I suggest the `DEL` button be disabled when the `=` button is pressed.

Answer (score -2):

It should be due to HTML. Be careful upadating textContent